# How to rearrange and equate the series coefficients in a Fourier-Bessel type equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to solve a system of equations involving Fourier-Bessel type equations. The equations read
$$
g_x = -\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \cos k\phi  f_1 (\lambda,k) \, , \\
g_y = -\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \sin k\phi f_2 (\lambda,k)  \, , 
$$
where
$$
g_x = g_R \cos \phi - g_\phi \sin \phi \, ,\\
g_y = g_R \sin \phi + g_\phi \cos \phi \, ,
$$
with
$$
g_R = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg( \psi_k(\lambda)\lambda I_k'(\lambda R) + \omega_k (\lambda) \frac{k}{R}  I_k (\lambda R) + \lambda^2 R \pi_k(\lambda) I_k''(\lambda R) \bigg) \cos k\phi 
$$
and 
$$
g_\phi =  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg( - \frac{k}{R}  \psi_k (\lambda) I_k(\lambda R) - \omega_k(\lambda) \lambda I_k'(\lambda R) + \left(  \frac{k}{R}  I_k(\lambda R) - k\lambda I_k'(\lambda R) \right)\pi_k(\lambda) \bigg) \sin k\phi \,
$$

Prime denotes differentiation with respect to the argument and $R$ is a positive number.
Here $\psi_k(\lambda)$, $\omega_k(\lambda)$ and $\pi_k(\lambda)$ are unknown functions.
The goal would be to rearrange and equate the Fourier coefficients to finally obtain 
$$
\lambda I_{k+1}(\lambda R) \psi_k(\lambda)-\lambda I_{k+1}(\lambda R) \omega_k(\lambda) + \lambda^2 R I_{k+1}'(\lambda R) \pi_k(\lambda) = -(f_1(\lambda,k)+f_2(\lambda,k)) \, , \\
\lambda I_{k-1}(\lambda R) \psi_k(\lambda)+\lambda I_{k-1}(\lambda R) \omega_k(\lambda) + \lambda^2 R I_{k-1}'(\lambda R) \pi_k(\lambda) = -(f_1(\lambda,k)-f_2(\lambda,k)) \, .
$$
I spent quite a lot of time to figure out how to proceed but in vain. I would be happy if someone here could provide with hints that can help a bit.

Thank you,